# Why does my executable jar not find the main class?

Tags: java, jar

Trying to export my java app from Eclipse into a runnable jar file. (It's a console app)

**This is what the project directory looks like in Eclipse:**

[image]

---

**This is what the run configuration of the project looks like:**

[image]

---

**This is what the jar creation options look like:**

[image]

---

**And finally, this is the error I get:**

[image]

I've literally tried everything and I'm so lost as to why it's not running. The main class is selected properly, the run configuration seems right, I tried both runnable and regular, BOTH don't work.

I tried cleaning, rebuilding, and even re-making the project and that didn't work.

I've researched this problem and everyone just suggests stuff like configurating the eclipse java path or making sure my app "isn't in a package" which doesn't make sense to me (aren't all java classes in a package)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you try running the file by clicking on it?

Comment: Can't do that if it's not a GUI app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to run an executable jar from the command line is:

```
java -jar "AlphaScript_Interactive V1.0.0.jar"
```

Comment: I tried that, it said it could not find the jar :o  Do I need the full path?

Comment: Yes, use full path.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wggq41   This is the error I get. "unable to access"

Comment: @katie1245 You didn't surround the file path in quotes. Your JAR file name has a space in it so in order for the shell to interpret as one argument you need to quote it.

Comment: THANK YOU!! It worked!!!!  I have a question though before I close this. Is this the only way to run a jar (console app)?

Comment: @katie1245 Only ways I know how to launch a JAR file is to either execute `java -jar <jarfile>` on the command line, or double-click the JAR file (if you've associated JAR files with Java). Note you don't have to necessarily pass the absolute path; it's enough to pass a path relative to the working directory.